# How to make tabs (ActionBar) stop calling onCreateView() of its neighbors tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar, android-lifecycle

I need my first tab, when I select it (after select the second), to call its `onCreateView()` or just its `onResume()`, or another function, to update it.

I have 2 tabs, what I do in the second tab have to change something in the first tab. But, when I'm in the first tab and I select the second, the `onCreateView()` of the first is called again. So, if I do something in the second tab and return to the first, nothing changes. To update the first, I had to go to the second again, to it call the onCreateView() of the first and then I have it updated.

I need the first tab to update itself when I select it, not when I select the second tab. I already tried the `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`, with no success.

How can I make it work?

Comment: U should show ur code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you're using a ViewPager. The reason `setOffsetPageLimit(0)` doesn't work is because 1 is the minimum value here.

You should create a callback that your Activity (or a class which can access both Fragments) implements, which the second Fragment can tell to update. You can then do logic in that callback to update your first Fragment.

I'd advise not doing the update in `onCreateView()` as you've mentioned because then it ties updates to the Fragment lifecycle - which is tricky to control.

Comment: Thanks @Espiandev ! I put the views which had to be updated as **static** and created a "**Manager.class**" that updates these views.